# Table With Fix Header And Column

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

this table scrolling in both horizontal and verticl side
using colspan and rowspan

how can i fix the header and first 3 column

I use Anglarjs to fill this table And I create it After click button

JSFiddle : [Sample Show](http://jsfiddle.net/farshi114/bnwh7chm/)

```
<table ng-show="pageState == 2"id="reportTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">ردیف</th>
            <th rowspan="3">سازمان های طرف قرارداد/منابع وصول درآمد</th>
            <th colspan="6">گردش عملیات سال ۱۳۸۹</th>
            <th colspan="9">گردش عملیات سال ۱۳۹۰</th>
            <th rowspan="3">كل  مطالبات (مانده ماه جاري+مانده سنواتي)   
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">مانده مطالبات سال ۱۳۸۹   قبل</th>
            <th rowspan="2">تفاوت تعرفه ارسالي سال ۱۳۸۹</th>
            <th rowspan="2">وصولی بابت  سال ۱۳۸۹ در سال ۱۳۹۰</th>
            <th rowspan="2">وصولي بابت تعرفه سال ۱۳۸۹ در سال ۱۳۹۰</th>
            <th rowspan="2">کسورات ۱۳۸۹</th>
            <th rowspan="2">مانده سنواتی</th>
            <th rowspan="2">مانده مطالبات سال ۱۳۹۰ انتقال از ماه قبل</th>
            <th colspan="3">ارسالي (اسناد +تفاوت تعرفه) ماه جاري</th>
            <th colspan="3">وصولي مربوط به سال ۱۳۹۰</th>
            <th rowspan="2">کسورات قطعی</th>
            <th rowspan="2">مانده ماه جاری</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>دارو</th>
            <th>درمان</th>
            <th>کلی</th>
            <th>دارو</th>
            <th>درمان</th>
            <th>کلی</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="sg in report">
            <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="18">
                <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <li >سازمانهای بیمه گر پايه  و ذغالسنگ</li></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۱</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName">کمیته امداد</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۵۱٬۰۰۰٬۰۰۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۲٬۱۱۰٬۰۰۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۵۱٬۰۰۰٬۰۰۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۱٬۹۹۹٬۰۰۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۱۰۰٬۰۰۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۱۱٬۰۰۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۱۱٬۰۰۰</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۲</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName">بازنشستگان فولاد</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۳</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName">بیمه سلامت</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۴</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName">تامین اجتماعی</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۵</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName">نیروهای مسلح</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۶</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName" class="ng-binding">ذغالسنگ(شاغل)</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="sg in report" class="ng-scope">
            <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="18">
                <ul><li>بانکهای طرف قرارداد</li></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۷</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName" class="ng-binding">بانک ملی</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۵۰٬۰۰۰٬۰۰۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۶۶٬۵۱۰٬۰۰۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۱۱۶٬۵۱۰٬۰۰۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۱۱۶٬۵۱۰٬۰۰۰</td>
        </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="sg in report" class="ng-scope">
            <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="18">
                <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <li>سایر سازمانها و شرکت های طرف قرارداد</li></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۸</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName" class="ng-binding">هلال احمر</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr><tr ng-repeat-start="sg in report" class="ng-scope">
            <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="18">
                <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <li >بیمه های تکمیلی طرف قرارداد</li></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۹</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName">بیمارستان 579 ارتش</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: r in sg.overlayReports --><tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-scope">
            <td class="ng-binding">۱۰</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName">آتیه سازان حافظ</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr><tr ng-repeat-start="sg in report" class="ng-scope">
            <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="18">
                <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><li>دانشگاه</li></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۱۱</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName">یارانه و طرح تحول نظام سلامت</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr><tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۱۲</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName">حوادث ترافیکی</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr><tr ng-repeat-start="sg in report" class="ng-scope">
            <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="18">
                <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><li></li></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="sg in report">
            <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="18">
                <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <li class="ng- binding">از طریق نقدی </li></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۱۳</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName" class="ng-binding">نقدی)</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr><tr ng-repeat-start="sg in report" class="ng-scope">
            <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="18">
                <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <li class="ng-binding">ییی</li></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in sg.overlayReports" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="ng-binding">۱۴</td>
            <td ng-bind="r.sourceName" class="ng-binding">یی</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">&lrm;۰</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="sg in report" class="ng-scope">
            <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="18">
                <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
               <li class="<ng-></ng->binding"></li></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to fix Header And First 3 Column From Rigth

Comment: What do you mean by fix? Do you want it fixed width?

Comment: Fix Header : When Scroll in table, header Still Show On Top

Answer (score 0):

give any element you want to be fixed an id like: `shouldBeFixed` and use this in your style sheet (CSS):

```
#shouldBeFixed{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: If I do that then scroll doesnot work any more on header

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the header is not quite easy. 
See this solution

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

but expect problems because you are using col-span and row-span. 
you will have to tweak it to work for you and fully test on all browsers.